# Display Form in ScrollPane

Tags: java, forms, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I created a form. Actually it is 10 JLabels with each JLabel having a text field next to it.

consider,

```
  JLabel_called_Name         JTextField_to_obtain_name
  JLabel_called_Phone        JTextField_to_obtain_phone_number
```

and so on..

I usually position this in a JPanel and display it in a frame. But my panel and frame have height smaller than the size required to hold 10 of these Labels and Textfields.

So I wish to add them to a JScrollPane.
But in every question I only obtained information of how to add Jlabels to a scroll pane using a Box,
or adding JLabels to a JList.

However I would like to represent it in the format I showed above. A Jlabel beside a JTextField.
How can one acheive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in every question I only obtained information of how to add Jlabels to a scroll pane using a Box, or adding JLabels to a JList.

You can add any component to a JScrollPane:

```
JPanel = new JPanel();
panel.add( label1 );
panel.add( textField1 );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
```

The trick is choosing the correct layout manager for you panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to help you decide how to design the panel. You can also nest panels to get your desired layout.